# How to implement pedometer functions in Android?

Tags: android, pedometer

I need to implement pedometer-like functions in my Android app. I need step count, distance walked, and average walking speed. I could certainly compute average walking speed myself and I could live without the step count, but the distance walked is what I need the most.

I looked at SensorManager. It has the step count, but not the distance walked. I can't just use GPS for that since GPS will not give me the accuracy I need. In my app the user is walking for short bursts of a few minutes.

I looked into the Fitness API too. It appears to be able to do what I want. However, after spending several hours getting through all of its permission requirements, it simply doesn't work. I get callbacks, but they have no data points.

What's the recommended approach here?

Comment: I think the most accurate would be Google Fit app - but on WearOS:
https://support.google.com/fit/answer/6098255

Comment: GPS will give you an order of magnitude more accuracy than the step sensor will.  Accelerometers are INCREDIBLY noisy

Comment: I don’t know if GPS will work. My app is directing users to do specific exercises. In one, we want to measure how far they can walk in 60 seconds. They could easily walk a curved path which means the distance between the start and end isn’t the distance walked. In another case we want to measure how fast they can run over a 30 second time window.